# Cluster documents if word the tokens in the document are encoded?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, apache-spark-mllib

I have to cluster documents (actually column names of a database) based on tokens present in the column name. For example:-

```
C1 = ["Date", "Birth"]  
C2 = ["Order", "Date"]  
C3 = ["Birth", "Day"]  
C4 = ["CUSTOMER", "FIRST", "NAME"]  
C5 = ["FIRST","NAME"]  
.
.
```

But all these tokens are actually encoded, so what I receive is following dataset.

```
C1 = ["44749712dbec183e983dcd78a7736c41", "e8329d2530ca7d80bb28176883186dfd"]  
C2 = ["a240fa27925a635b08dc28c9e4f9216d", "44749712dbec183e983dcd78a7736c41"]  
C3 = ["e8329d2530ca7d80bb28176883186dfd", "03727ac48595a24daed975559c944a44"]  
C4 = ["979ee13f032c02b4652a4e3c3928d90b", "2c2624a5059934a947d6e25fe8332ade", "ad32e604e17467fc435538334fbddf3e"]  
C5 = ["2c2624a5059934a947d6e25fe8332ade","ad32e604e17467fc435538334fbddf3e"]  
.  
.
```

Now I want to cluster by consuming he encoded values such that
C1, C2, C3 -> Cluster 1
C4, C5 -> Cluster 2

I am currently out of depths on how to do that. Is there any machine learning algorithm which can solve my problem?

I am currently using Spark MLlib 1.6.0 but I couldn't find a way to apply algorithm such as Word2Vec to solve my problem.

Is it possible to use word2vec or algorithm on the unencoded dataset?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the encoding should not be a problem as the encoding is uniform, for example, the 'Birth' keyword in document C1 and C3 are same 'e8329d2530ca7d80bb28176883186dfd'. As for the vector space mapping of the key works, you could collect all the key words and take a vector of equivalent length and mark the vector position as '1' if the keyword is present or '0' if it is not. There are however many ways to map documents to vector space. [Refer this semila book by Jurafsk & Martin](http://www.deepsky.com/~merovech/voynich/voynich_manchu_reference_materials/PDFs/jurafsky_martin.pdf). As for the exact model to perform the clustering there are too many methods to list here, start with someting simple like K-Mean or K-Nearest Neighbour, there are also many options available in ANN space.

Comment: I don't have all the keywords beforehand. The will get the keywords as I continue to scan the database(columns) like a scanning job. how to create the vector space model then?   Thanks for reference book

Comment: It depends if you can rescan the columns or if it has to be in one go. Simpler would be making the vector space as a pre-processing step and then rescan to actually build the datapoints. It could be done in one go as well but is more complicated.

Comment: The total number of columns to be scanned will be greater than 10 million. It is not possible to scan the whole dataset at a single. It maybe be possible that another 10 million columns may come at a later point of time

Comment: 10 million is a moderately small number in machine learning space, just use adequate hardware and pre-process.

Comment: My point is what will happen if I have to scan a new data center(say with 100 million) after scanning for example 500 million column. Wouldn't the vector length be very large in this way?

Comment: Yes, it would be large but that is not the topic of your question. Open a new question to discuss the big data angle.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get easier by trying to mix in the latest hypes like word2vec and Spark. Use only what you need, not what is fancy.

First you will need a similarity. Consider each column as a *set* (no encoding necessary), and then compute Jaccard index or similar. Then do HAC for clustering.

Comment: I am getting each column in an encoding format. I can't apply Jaccard to the encoded format

Comment: Sure you can apply Jaccard to the encoded format. Why not?